# Geo-location by Zip/Postal Code

Tags: geolocation, ip-geolocation

I'm looking for a service to get a latitude/longitude dynamically by zip/postal code.

I also need this service to give me an address (city/state/country) by providing an IP Address.

I will be using this service on my website and don't want to download and maintain a database.

I looked at a few services, some too expensive and some free with a max amount of daily/monthly lookups.

What are some good free services and what are some good paid services (Not too expensive) that allow for a large amount of queries?

I am using asp.net c# with MS SQL Server 2008 or later.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A comment: The economics of this are pretty simple: it costs money for the service provider to give the infrastructure and if it is of value to you, then their cost to you should be less than that value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For lat/long: Google and Yahoo allow for several thousand queries per day, at least the last time I used them.

For GeoIP lookup, I can't say. In the past, I've used aggregate data from Google AdWords.  This may be true of other advertising networks, or some may give you info per user.

Comment: Google will work for geo look up by address/zip: (Max: 2,500 requests per day)
[The Google Geocoding API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/)

GeoPlugin should work well for me as a web service to lookup by IP Address. This is free but not as accurate as Google.
[http://www.geoplugin.com/](http://www.geoplugin.com/)

But because I want a service I know will be up 99.999% of the time, i'm going to possibly purchase a database from [MaxMind](http://www.maxmind.com/app/city)  or [zipcodedownload](http://www.zipcodedownload.com/Products/Category/Bundle/).

Comment: Excellent.  I think purchasing a DB is the right way to go for the long-term rather than a one-off project.  Over time you may find little glitches in the data, and it's easier to normalize when the database is in-house.

Answer (score 2):

The US zip codes are free (maybe just not very well maintained):
http://www.census.gov/geo/www/tiger/tigermap.html#ZIP

Also see a (whole world) crowd sourcing project:
http://www.freethepostcode.org/

The database of the UK zip code location was leaked last year or so. Or maybe it was made public by some government scheme I can't remember. It is definitely available here: http://www.freepostcodes.org.uk/

Comment: I require USA/Canada postal codes and possibly the entire world later on.